# Is it possible to redirect login page instead of index.php in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4

Based on my requirement I should redirect customer login page  `$this->_redirect('customer/account/login/');`.
Is it possible to redirect login page instead of `index.php` in magento?

thanks.

Comment: can you please update the details from where you have to do redirect.

Comment: @KeyulShah, see updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i have understood is you want to redirect customer to login page if he is not logged in if that is the case than use this extension developed by bijal bhawsar, hope it will help you.

https://github.com/bijalbhavsar/Restrictpage

Comment: yes... exactly this is what I expected. thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to add only one thing

```
 $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
```

When you put this line it will redirect to the Index page of your site.

Comment: if I want to redirect `$this->_redirect('customer/account/login/');` where should I write this.

Comment: same you ask the question it will redirect tot the account controller and call the login method

Comment: I know redirect method description. I mean which file I should write this line of code?

Comment: I know redirect method description. I mean which file I should write this line of code?

Comment: you have to override the account controller and write the code in login method